# Problems with import, __init__.py with .ipynb

Tags: python, init, code-organization

I'm a beginner organizing my code properly in python and I am struggling a bit doing imports in my main `.ipynb` from a `.py` script.

My folder is organized as it follows:

```
|   naive.ipynb
|   requirements.txt
|
+---data
|       DNA_train.txt
|       pseudomona.feather
|       pseudo_test.csv
|       pseudo_train.csv
|
+---model
|       dna_token.model
|
\---src
        token_dna_converter.py
        __init__.py
```

As I have read, to be able to import classes from a different folder, I should add a `__init__.py` file to able access from a super folder. In the `__init__.py` I put the following:

`from .token_dna_converter import tokenDNA`

Afterwards, I want to call this script in a notebook and I have tried the following:

`from token_dna_converter import tokenDNA`

However, the .ipynb does not detect this inner "package"...
I don't know why and I am struggling to try to fix this.

Does anyone know how should I properly call this script? I would appreciate everything!

Comment: the `__init__.py` make it so the given folder being treated as a python package and being able to be imported, and what you get from the import is whatever is in the `__init__.py`, but the name you need to use for this import is the name of the folder (and folder being reachable by the import machinery), given that your .ipynb is outside, as it stand the import you need is `from src import tokenDNA`

Comment: generally, if you are using a src layout, you dont' put an `__init__.py` in the `src` folder, that is the root of the source code.

Comment: Anyway, the issue is that there is no `token_dna_converter` in the path. Python will search this path for modules. "installing" is mostly putting that package in the path.